# App keeps crashing when login button is clicked

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

When I click the Login or Register button the app completely crashes. I cant seem to figure out what the issue is.  I'm new to Android so any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Login Java Class

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private Button mLogin;
private EditText mEmail, mPassword;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthStateListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user !=null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    };


    mLogin = findViewById(R.id.Login);

    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.Password);

    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "sign in error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
}
```

}

Registration Java class

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mRegister;
private EditText mEmail, mPassword, mName;

private RadioGroup mRadioGroup;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthStateListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

     mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    if (user !=null){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        return;
            }
        }
    };


    mRegister = findViewById(R.id.Register);

    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.Password);
    mName = findViewById(R.id.name);

    mRadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int selectId = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            final RadioButton radioButton = findViewById(selectId);

            if(radioButton.getText() == null){
                return;
            }

            final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            final String name = mName.getText().toString();
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(RegistrationActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference currentUserDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
                        Map userInfo = new HashMap<>();
                        userInfo.put("name", name);
                        userInfo.put("sex", radioButton.getText().toString());
                        userInfo.put("profileImageUrl", "default");
                        currentUserDb.updateChildren(userInfo);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
}
```

}

Here are the errors I receive from the Logcat:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:186)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@18.1.0:1)
        at mothership.example.room8.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)

Comment: The error you pasted here is not from your app, this is just your phone's log. Please set your logs to show only selected option on the right corner of LogCat tab, then look for the error that has your app's package name on left side.

Comment: [This article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Debugging-Exceptions-within-your-App#find-the-stack-trace) may help you to find out your fatal exception. Please attach it to your question

Comment: Okay Ill give it  read. Thanks man!

Comment: The article helped. I went ahead and made the changes to the LogCat Errors I originally posted.

Comment: ```Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing the `FirebaseApp`. In `onCreate()`, write this first:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Do this in both of your activities `onCreate()`

Also add following dependencies:

**In your project level gradle file:**

```
dependencies {
  ....
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
}
```

**In your app level gradle file:**

Add this on top of the file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```